# Selecting single table data into 5 columns columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can some tell me what is wrong with following oracle query?
I am trying to get data from single column into 5 different columns based an block number and Date as common condition

Thanks in advance

```
select WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO, t1.WBD_VALUE, t2.WBD_VALUE, t3.WBD_VALUE,
       t4.WBD_VALUE, t5.WBD_VALUE
from WB_BLOCK_DATA, 
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO
     from WB_BLOCK_DATA
     where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692583'
       and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month')) = 'January'
       and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017') as t1,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO
     from WB_BLOCK_DATA
     where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692599'
       and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month')) = 'January'
       and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017') as t2,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO
     from WB_BLOCK_DATA
     where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692607'
       and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month')) = 'January'
       and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017') as t3,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO
     from WB_BLOCK_DATA
     where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692615'
       and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month')) = 'January'
       and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017') as t4,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO
     from WB_BLOCK_DATA
     where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692623'
       and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month')) = 'January'
       and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017') as t5
where WBD_DATE = t1.WBD_DATE 
  and WBD_DATE = t2.WBD_DATE 
  and WBD_DATE = t3.WBD_DATE 
  and WBD_DATE = t4.WBD_DATE 
  and WBD_DATE = t5.WBD_DATE 
  and WBD_BLOCK_NO = t1.WBD_BLOCK_NO
  and WBD_BLOCK_NO = t2.WBD_BLOCK_NO
  and WBD_BLOCK_NO = t3.WBD_BLOCK_NO
  and WBD_BLOCK_NO = t4.WBD_BLOCK_NO
  and WBD_BLOCK_NO = t5.WBD_BLOCK_NO
```

Comment: Please add the error message. It's quite hard to guess the error without.

Answer (score 1):

`AS` is not supported for tables alias in Oracle, but only for columns; also, you need to use an alias even for `WB_BLOCK_DATA` , or refer to its columns as `WB_BLOCK_DATA.columnName`.

```
select t0.WBD_DATE, t0.WBD_BLOCK_NO, t1.WBD_VALUE, t2.WBD_VALUE, t3.WBD_VALUE,      t4.WBD_VALUE, t5.WBD_VALUE
from WB_BLOCK_DATA t0, 
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO from WB_BLOCK_DATA where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692583' and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month'))='January' and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017')  t1,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO from WB_BLOCK_DATA where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692599' and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month'))='January' and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017')  t2,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO from WB_BLOCK_DATA where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692607' and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month'))='January' and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017')  t3,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO from WB_BLOCK_DATA where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692615' and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month'))='January' and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017')  t4,
    (select WBD_VALUE, WBD_DATE, WBD_BLOCK_NO from WB_BLOCK_DATA where WBD_ATTRIBUTE_ID = '2692623' and trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month'))='January' and to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')='2017')  t5
    where t0.WBD_DATE = t1.WBD_DATE 
      and t0.WBD_DATE = t2.WBD_DATE 
      and t0.WBD_DATE = t3.WBD_DATE 
      and t0.WBD_DATE = t4.WBD_DATE 
      and t0.WBD_DATE = t5.WBD_DATE 
      and t0.WBD_BLOCK_NO = t1.WBD_BLOCK_NO
      and t0.WBD_BLOCK_NO = t2.WBD_BLOCK_NO
      and t0.WBD_BLOCK_NO = t3.WBD_BLOCK_NO
      and t0.WBD_BLOCK_NO = t4.WBD_BLOCK_NO
      and t0.WBD_BLOCK_NO = t5.WBD_BLOCK_NO
```

Example:

```
SQL> select dummy from dual x;

D
-
X

SQL> select dummy from dual as x;
select dummy from dual as x
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


SQL> select dummy as d from dual x;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for correction, I am a newbie and I only use oracle as part of reporting purpose in our projects. After correcting the same I get error as column ambiguously defined.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside (and this is really too long to fit in as a comment, which is what it really is), what you are trying to do is known as a pivot operation. If you are on Oracle 11.1 or higher, you can do this using the PIVOT operator:

```
WITH wb_block_data AS (SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692583' wbd_attribute_id, 10 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692599' wbd_attribute_id, 20 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692607' wbd_attribute_id, 30 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692615' wbd_attribute_id, 40 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692623' wbd_attribute_id, 50 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692671' wbd_attribute_id, 60 wbd_value FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table with some sample data in it. See SQL below:
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   wb_block_data
        WHERE  wbd_attribute_id IN ('2692583', '2692599', '2692607', '2692615', '2692623')
        and    TRUNC(wbd_date, 'mm') = to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
PIVOT (MAX(wbd_value) FOR (wbd_attribute_id) IN ('2692583' AS attrib_2692583,
                                                 '2692599' AS attrib_2692599,
                                                 '2692607' AS attrib_2692607,
                                                 '2692615' AS attrib_2692615,
                                                 '2692623' AS attrib_2692623));

WBD_DATE    WBD_BLOCK_NO ATTRIB_2692583 ATTRIB_2692599 ATTRIB_2692607 ATTRIB_2692615 ATTRIB_2692623
----------- ------------ -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
12/01/2017             1             10             20             30             40             50
```

If you are on an earlier version, you can use the following to manually do the pivot:

```
WITH wb_block_data AS (SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692583' wbd_attribute_id, 10 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692599' wbd_attribute_id, 20 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692607' wbd_attribute_id, 30 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692615' wbd_attribute_id, 40 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692623' wbd_attribute_id, 50 wbd_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT to_date('12/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') wbd_date, 1 wbd_block_no, '2692671' wbd_attribute_id, 60 wbd_value FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table with some sample data in it. See SQL below:
SELECT wbd_date,
       wbd_block_no,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wbd_attribute_id = '2692583' THEN wbd_value END) attrib_2692583,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wbd_attribute_id = '2692599' THEN wbd_value END) attrib_2692599,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wbd_attribute_id = '2692607' THEN wbd_value END) attrib_2692607,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wbd_attribute_id = '2692615' THEN wbd_value END) attrib_2692615,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wbd_attribute_id = '2692623' THEN wbd_value END) attrib_2692623
FROM   wb_block_data
WHERE  wbd_attribute_id IN ('2692583', '2692599', '2692607', '2692615', '2692623')
and    TRUNC(wbd_date, 'mm') = to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
GROUP BY wbd_date, wbd_block_no;

WBD_DATE    WBD_BLOCK_NO ATTRIB_2692583 ATTRIB_2692599 ATTRIB_2692607 ATTRIB_2692615 ATTRIB_2692623
----------- ------------ -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
12/01/2017             1             10             20             30             40             50
```

Note how in both cases, I've amended the predicates to compare the date to a date, rather than splitting the date into two strings and then comparing those. Also note that I truncated the wbd_date to the month level (which automatically means the first day of the month). It also means that if you want to use an index, you only need to define it on a single element: `trunc(wbd_date, 'mm')` rather than on two elements: `trim(to_char(WBD_DATE, 'Month'))` and `to_char(WBD_DATE, 'YYYY')`

Comment: Thank you Boneist, I checked it in 11g it works perfectly. But I am passing December as month and Year as YYYY to my report that is the reason i am taking as two elements

Comment: so, do `trunc(wbd_date, 'mm') = to_date('01/'||:p_month||'/'||:p_year, 'dd/Month/yyyy')` instead, then. And if you absolutely must stick to splitting the date into two parts, at least get rid of the trim and amend the to_char format mask appropriately to remove the extra characters: `to_char(WBD_DATE, 'fmMonth')` (but I would advise against splitting the date column into two strings, since it'll be less performant than running a single trunc function on the column.)